# Do genitals need to be censored even in non-pornographic works in Japan?

Tags: japan

Building on [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24829/how-far-does-japanese-censorship-law-go), I want to know how the law is interpreted for things that just happen to feature nudity, but aren't meant to be consumed as "pornographic material". Example: sculptures, images or 3d models of naked people. How does the law treat these things? Does it matter if it's pornographic in nature or does the mere presence of genitals require it to be censored in some way?

Answer (score 1):

If the work is determined to have artistic merit, even if it might be considered by some as "obscene", [it seems Japan will eventually find it's OK](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/02/20/arts/20arts-SUPREMECOURT_BRF.html). So photos of classical sculptures/statues should be fine. Photos of people, or 3D nude models, possibly, depending on content and context. But you may face a legal battle unless the work is very clearly for artistic and not pornographic reasons.